# How do I get vim to keep its undo history?

Tags: vim

If I'm editing two files with vim, changing to the other file ( :bnext, :bprev ) seems to drop the undo history from the open file - hitting the 'u' key reports "Already at oldest change".

For example:

1. `vim testfile1 testfile2`
2. add some stuff to testfile1
3. `:w`
4. `:bn`
5. `:bp`
6. `u`
7. eep! can't undo!

Is there any way to keep this history for non-visible buffers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to put this in your *~/.vimrc* file:

```
set hid
```

Answer (score 7):

For Vim 7.3+, there is another way that I believe applies in this case. In `$VIMRC`:

```
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
set undofile
```

The `undodir` needs to exist.

From Vim's help:

```
                        *'undodir'* *'udir'*
'undodir' 'udir'    string  (default ".")
            global
            {not in Vi}
            {only when compiled with the |+persistent_undo| feature}
    List of directory names for undo files, separated with commas.
    See |'backupdir'| for details of the format.
    "." means using the directory of the file.  The undo file name for
    "file.txt" is ".file.txt.un~".
    For other directories the file name is the full path of the edited
    file, with path separators replaced with "%".
    When writing: The first directory that exists is used. "." always
    works, no directories after "." will be used for writing.
    When reading all entries are tried to find an undo file.  The first
    undo file that exists is used.  When it cannot be read an error is
    given, no further entry is used.
    See |undo-persistence|.

                        *'undofile'* *'udf'*
'undofile' 'udf'    boolean (default off)
            local to buffer
            {not in Vi}
            {only when compiled with the |+persistent_undo| feature}
    When on, Vim automatically saves undo history to an undo file when
    writing a buffer to a file, and restores undo history from the same
    file on buffer read.
    The directory where the undo file is stored is specified by 'undodir'.
    For more information about this feature see |undo-persistence|.
    The undo file is not read when 'undoreload' causes the buffer from
    before a reload to be saved for undo.
    WARNING: this is a very new feature.  Use at your own risk!
```

Comment: If I move a file/directory, is it possible to preserve the undo-history of a file?

Comment: @alpha_989: Well, you can read undo history from an arbitrary file using `:rundo`, which means you can load the undo history from the old undo file. It is also possible to just rename the undo file according to Vim's scheme (replace directory separator with `%`) in the undo directory to make it apply to the moved file, _if_ the content corresponds to what the undo file expects. If you want more than that, we might be moving into version control territory :-) .

Comment: Thanks very helpful

Comment: @DanielAndersson That's untrue. Vim provides this exact feature with `:saveas`. @alpha_989 With this command, you can rename/move a file while still preserving undo history and not having to do it by hand like Daniel said.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the file and explicitly mention the name of the `undo-file`: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/8b1f7d8774b235ae4f0dc0fa64d58e3cad9f8283/runtime/doc/undo.txt#L269